# How to change MySQL column definition?

Tags: mysql, alter-table

I have a mySQL table called test:

```
create table test(
    locationExpect varchar(120) NOT NULL;
);
```

I want to change the locationExpect column to:

```
create table test(
    locationExpect varchar(120);
);
```

How can it be done quickly?

Answer (score 300, accepted):

Do you mean altering the table after it has been created? If so you need to use [alter table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html), in particular:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY COLUMN new-column-definition
```

e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE test MODIFY COLUMN locationExpect VARCHAR(120);
```

Comment: So... MySQLWorkbench has a syntax checking bug that rejects this command. But, it's the right command.

Comment: Beware: The above example will also change COLUMN to Null=Yes, Default=Null.  You need to specify different values if you don't want Null.

Comment: @GuyGordon in the original question [Mask](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179364/mask) wanted to change a column from `NOT NULL` to allowing nulls so I think this example is still OK. Agree that a slight variation would be needed if a different default was wanted though.

Answer (score 43):

Syntax to **change column name** in **MySql**:

```
alter table table_name change old_column_name new_column_name data_type(size);
```

Example:

```
alter table test change LowSal Low_Sal integer(4);
```

Answer (score 10):

This should do it:

```
ALTER TABLE test MODIFY locationExpert VARCHAR(120)
```