# As defined in mysql

Tags: mysql

Hello i have table which in this table some of the field are optional to be filled.

what i want that whenever the user is not filling the optional fields the table must take

the value of N/A on those optional fields.

i have used As Defined in structure of fields as value of  N/A but whenever i m submitting the

html form its not taking its value and the field is remaining empty.

Any one has any idea please.

Comment: Make the fields non-nullable and set a default value of "N/A" in the table definition?

Comment: i can not find the non-nullable in GUI can u write plz the query for an existing field.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595372/how-to-change-mysql-column-definition (or a Google search for "MySQL alter table change column")

Comment: You should make the field nullable and substitute "N/A" only in the UI whenever you output the data. This can even be done in the query when retrieving the data. Don't store "N/A" in the database, it makes no sense. The SQL representation of a "non existing value" is `NULL`.

Comment: sorry bro i have tried lots of commands for making fields non-nullable but i haven't succeeded can u plz write the command for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inserting it with empty value from variable, to get the default value of mysql field you will required to use `DEFAULT` as value this keyword will insert whatever you have given in as defined value

```
INSERT INTO table_name 
     (fname, lname, phone, fax) 
VALUES
     ('Jhon', 'Do', DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
```

**Edit**

To do it using php create a simple function to handle inputs with a provision for default value like this

```
function post($key, $default = 'N/A') {
   return ( isset($_POST[$key]) && !empty($_POST[$key]) ) ? $_POST[$key] : $default;
}
```

that way you don't have to get a default value by using `$var = post('phone')`

In you case you can use it like

```
$information = post('moreaboutgeneralinfo');
```

and if you want default value other than `N/A` pass second param

```
$information = post('moreaboutgeneralinfo', 'Not Available');
```

Hope above helps

Comment: ya it worked but my fields are optional may the user fill it or may not how to declare both my $var and DEFAULT in query.

Comment: @user3724705 check now hope this helps

Comment: its not working i have copied all code plz check it. "$connection=new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_pass, $db_name);
if($connection->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $connection->connect_error . ']');
}


function post($key, $default = 'N/A') 

{
   return ( isset($_POST[$key]) && !empty($_POST[$key]) ) ? $_POST[$key] : $default;
}

$information = $_POST['moreaboutgeneralinfo'];

$query= "INSERT INTO student(id, name) values('', '".$information."')";

$query_run = $connection->query($query);

if($query)
{
 echo 'success';
}
else
{
 echo 'failed';
}
"

Comment: yes key will the input name form html

Comment: its not working i have pasted the code above plz check it once

Comment: use `$information = post('moreaboutgeneralinfo');` instead `$information = $_POST['moreaboutgeneralinfo'];` and it will work

Answer (score 0):

You can use following queries:-

```
ALTER TABLE TAB_NAME MODIFY COL_NAME DATATYPE(SIZE) NOT NULL;
```

And then for adding default constraint:-

```
ALTER TABLE TAB_NAME ALTER COL_NAME SET DEFAULT 'N/A';
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: the queries performed, but whenever i m inserting data via my HTML+PHP form so its not taking the value of 'N/A'. its taking empty.

Comment: Then you can handle this at front end as well. means where there is a null value, you can convert this into a string like 'N/A'. and then try to insert this value to database.