# Not able to alter a column to accept null values for int datatype

Tags: mysql

Query :

ALTER TABLE db.tbl_name ALTER COLUMN column_name INT NULL

Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INT NULL' at line 1

Comment: MODIFY COLUMN, not ALTER

Comment: Suprised to see that much of the answers in SO have it ALTER. Is this issue version related?

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following:

```
ALTER TABLE db.tbl_name Modify COLUMN column_name INT NULL
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595372/how-to-change-mysql-column-definition) is a good read :)