# Why this sql statement doesn't working ----"ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN email varchar(100) not null;"----?

Tags: mysql

-***ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN email varchar(100) not null;***

What's the solution?
Why this statement doesn't working?

Comment: Please go read [ask] first of all.

Comment: And search the web for how to modify a column.
See i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595372/how-to-change-mysql-column-definition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can try like this

```
ALTER TABLE table_name  ADD  email varchar(100) not null
```

you can change column name

```
ALTER TABLE tableName RENAME COLUMN "oldcolname" TO "newcolname" datatype(length);
```

you can modify also

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY COLUMN column_name datatype;
```