# I'm using the ALTER TABLE statement and having issues SQL

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to use ALTER TABLE in MySQL and having no luck. Any feedback is much appreciated.

```
ALTER TABLE customers
ALTER COLUMN Phone VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
```

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong. I already tried:

```
ALTER TABLE customers
ALTER COLUMN Phone VARCHAR(200) [NOT NULL]
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE customers
ALTER COLUMN Phone VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL;
```

Comment: ALTER TABLE..MODIFY COLUMN

Comment: What do you mean by "have no luck"? Is there any error message?

Comment: Are you seeing any error?

Comment: It says that I have an error in my SQL Syntax, but that is all I have on my screen

Comment: Thanks for the help folks!! It's solved!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change MySQL column definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595372/how-to-change-mysql-column-definition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this if you're using MySQL

```
ALTER TABLE customers MODIFY COLUMN phone VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL;
```