# How do I alter a table column from decimal to varchar

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering if I could alter an SQL table column from decimal to varchar.

My table name is called "products", and I want to change the column "qty" to varchar.

What I want the final result to be:

- The column qty in table products to be varchar instead of decimal

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.    However, why would you want `qty` to be a string?  A number seems very reasonable.

Comment: Do you really want to hold a quantity as a varchar? Like qty = 'TEN' ?? I doubt it will be a good idea in the long run

Comment: This sounds like bad design to me. If you need an extra information it will be better to create a new column to hold this. For example, if you need to store "2kg", store 2 in qty and kg in this new varchar column.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to change the data type?  That could help us answer the question / give you a better design choice.

Comment: Ok! Thank you all for the ideas. 
I should try the one you told @FelippeDuarte

Comment: And, the reason why I wanted to change it is because I wanted people to enter a label after the number (for example: 1 box, or 1 container), not just the number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on answer from [How to change MySQL column definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595372/how-to-change-mysql-column-definition)

Follow syntax `ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN <column_name> <type>;`

Therefore in your case it will be:

```
ALTER TABLE products MODIFY COLUMN qty VARCHAR(desired_characters);
```

`desired_characters` should define how many characters your `varchar` should contain.

However I recommend use `int` for quantity type fields. Additionally you can mark it as unsigned since quantity cannot be negative.

```
ALTER TABLE products MODIFY COLUMN qty int unsigned;
```